# How to return all possible categories separated by | under one column

Tags: r, text-mining

I have a dataset "movie" that has a column named "genre", its values are like "Action", "Action|Animation", "Animation|Fantasy". A movie can have more than one genre. I would like to output a list of all possible single categories (such as Adventure, Fantasy) and their frequencies. In other words, I want to know how many movies have genre "action", how many have "fantasy". I don't care about the combinations. Are there any advice on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one simple way to do in base `R` using `sapply`

```
# sample data frame
df <- data.frame(genre=c("Action", "Action|Animation", "Animation|Fantasy"), stringsAsFactors = F)

# get uniq genre
uniq.genre <- unique(unlist(strsplit(df$genre, split = '\\|')))

# get frequency
sapply(uniq.genre, function(genre) {
  sum(grepl(genre, df$genre))
})
#>    Action Animation   Fantasy 
#>         2         2         1
```

Answer (score 0):

One option, if there are not too much genres, is to use the function `grepl()` that will tell you if a specific string (like `'Action'`) appears in a character (like `'Animation|Fantasy'`):

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

data.frame(
  genre = c('Action', 'Fantasy|Action', 'Animation|Fantasy')
) %>% 
  mutate(
    isAction    = grepl('Action', genre),
    isAdventure = grepl('Adventure', genre),
    isAnimation = grepl('Animation', genre),
    isComedy    = grepl('Comedy', genre),
    isFantasay  = grepl('Fantasy', genre)
  )

#               genre isAction isAdventure isAnimation isComedy isFantasay
# 1            Action     TRUE       FALSE       FALSE    FALSE      FALSE
# 2    Fantasy|Action     TRUE       FALSE       FALSE    FALSE       TRUE
# 3 Animation|Fantasy    FALSE       FALSE        TRUE    FALSE       TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

If the intention is to find the frequency of each genre, then we do a `split` on the 'genre' column by the delimiter `|` and use `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(strsplit(as.character(df1$genre), "|", fixed = TRUE))
```

---

Or using `table` from `base R`

```
dat <- stack(setNames(strsplit(as.character(df1$genre), "|", 
           fixed = TRUE), seq_len(nrow(df1))))
lvls <- c("Action', 'Adventure', 'Animation', 'Comedy', 'Fantasy')
dat$values <- factor(dat$values, levels = lvls)
table(dat[2:1])
```

NOTE: Assuming that all categories are found in the dataset